# Convergence of finite difference scheme for conservation law

Tags: numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations, finite-difference-methods, finite-volume-method

I am currently studying for a test and came across this problem. The PDE is given by $$u_t + f(u)_x = 0 $$
where $f(u) = u^2/2$ , $u$ is periodic with period $2 \pi$ in $x$, and $u(x,0) =u_0(x)$ is  a given smooth periodic function. The problem gives us the two step finite different scheme \begin{align*}
\hat{u}_j^{n+1} &= u_j^n - \lambda (f(u_{j+1}^n)-f(u_j^n)) \\
u_{j}^{n+1} &= \frac{1}{2}(u_j^n + \hat{u}_j^{n+1}) - \frac{\lambda}{2}(f(\hat{u}_{j}^{n+1})-f(\hat{u}_{j-1}^{n+1}))
\end{align*}
and asks us to find a constraint on $\lambda = \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}$ so that the scheme converges as $\Delta x, \Delta t \to 0$. According to chapter 12 in [this text](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1470/c6f43c769572c4cfc94ffc9c5710484ff1e5.pdf), a method will converge to the weak solution if it is consistent with the conservation law, the numerical flux function is Lipschitz continuous, and the method is $TV$ stable. Consistency should just follow by doing taylor expansions. I determined the numerical flux function to be $F(u_j^n,u_j^{n+1}) = \frac{f(\hat{u}_{j}^{n+1}) + f(u_{j+1}^n)}{2}$, which is Lipschitz in its arguments. I am not so sure how to prove TV-stability though. In the pdf, the author generally will prove TV-stability by first proving that the method is $L_1$ contracting, i.e $$\|u^{n+1} \|_1 \leq \| u^{n} \|_1,  $$

but I've had no luck showing this. Am I going about this the right way? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes thank you! There was a couple of typos. The scheme should be correct now, and was what I was originally working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [MacCormack method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacCormack_method) (see also this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Wendroff_method), Sec. *Jacobian free methods*) for the inviscid Burgers equation. Combining both steps, we can rewrite the method as
$$
u_j^{n+1} = u_j^n - \frac{\lambda}{2} \big(f(u_{j+1}^n) + f(\hat u_j^{n+1}) - f(u_{j}^n) - f(\hat u_{j-1}^{n+1}) \big)
$$
with $\hat u_j^{n+1} = u_j^n - \lambda\big(f(u_{j+1}^n) - f(u_j^n)\big)$.
Thus, the flux function proposed in OP is correct, and the scheme is consistent. It remains to prove stability.

Instead of proving the $L_1$-contraction property (as proposed in OP), let us prove the $l_1$-contraction property (see [1], p. 167-168). For this purpose, let's introduce $w_j^n = u_j^n - v_j^n$ with compact support. We introduce also $\hat w_j^{n+1} = \hat u_j^{n+1} - \hat v_j^{n+1}$, which is given by
$$
\hat w_j^{n+1} = w_j^n - \lambda \big(f(u_{j+1}^n) - f(v_{j+1}^n) - f(u_{j}^n) + f(v_{j}^n)\big) .
$$
In what follows, we'll make use of the fact that $f(b)-f(a) = \frac{a+b}{2}(b-a)$. By using the scheme's formula above, we rewrite $w_j^{n+1} = u_j^{n+1} - v_j^{n+1}$ as
$$
w_j^{n+1} = \left(1 + \frac{\lambda}{2}\tfrac{u_{j}^n + v_{j}^n}{2} \right)w_j^n - \frac{\lambda}{2} \left(\tfrac{u_{j+1}^n + v_{j+1}^n}{2}w_{j+1}^n + \tfrac{\hat u_{j}^{n+1} + \hat v_{j}^{n+1}}{2}\hat w_{j}^{n+1} - \tfrac{\hat u_{j-1}^{n+1} + \hat v_{j-1}^{n+1}}{2}\hat w_{j-1}^{n+1} \right)
$$
with
$\displaystyle
\hat w_j^{n+1} = \left(1+\lambda\tfrac{u_{j}^n + v_{j}^n}{2}\right)w_j^n - \lambda \tfrac{u_{j+1}^n + v_{j+1}^n}{2}w_{j+1}^n
$. To complete the proof, it remains to prove that $\|w^{n+1}\|_1 \leqslant \|w^{n}\|_1$.
Alternatively, it may be simpler to try proving that $$\|w^{n+1}\|_1\leqslant \|\hat w^{n+1}\|_1 \leqslant \|w^{n}\|_1$$ under a given CFL restriction. This property would then imply $l_1$-contraction and thus TV-stability.

[1] R.J. LeVeque, *Numerical Methods for Conservation Laws*, Birkhauser, 1992.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Using the fact that $f(b)-f(a) = \frac{a+b}{2} (b-a)$ definitely helped simplify things, but my resulting expression is still extremely complicated, to the point where I don't believe we can prove $l_1$ contraction. Likewise for proving that the method is monotone, there doesn't appear to be any way to choose $\lambda$ so that all the partial derivatives are positive. LeVeque does state the method is second order, which means it can't be monotone by theorem 15.6. Do you think there is some other method to show stability?

Comment: @MikeD Just a thought: the first step is an upwind difference. Thus, the stability of that step is easily analyzed. Remains to work on that second step, which may be viewed as the linear average between $u_j^n$ and a downwind difference of the first step...

Comment: @MikeD It may have been a mistake to write the formula in one step. We may take advantage of the intermediate step if we manage to prove $\|w^{n+1}\| \leq \|\hat w^{n+1}\|\leq \|w^{n}\|$ under a given CFL restriction

Comment: I've been fiddling around with this but no luck. Not sure how I would show $\|  \hat{w}^{n+1} \| \leq \| w^n \|_1$, since we really have no control over the signs of the coefficients of $w_j^n$ and $w_{j+1}^n$. By any chance, would you know if linearization, and then Von Neumann Analysis would be a possible strategy?

Comment: @MikeD Possibly. However, you should linearize for $f(u)=u+\frac12 u^2$ instead of $f(u)=\frac12 u^2$. Otherwise it's not very interesting... For the linear case, you may have a look at [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02253461) [doi:10.1007/BF02253461] and references therein